# Install .ipa file without iTunes?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

Is it Possible Install .ipa to iphone  iTunes ?

Any 3rd party sites like iTunes?

**Ex : https://tryouts.io/ , https://appetize.io/**

Comment: You can use TestFlight, XCode.

Comment: I don't have apple developer account XCode needs that.

Comment: You don't need Developer account to install IPA through XCode it is required to create IPA, just open XCode, goto Devices from Window menu, select your device, you will be able to see an interface saying Installed Apps, click on + and choose your IPA it will install, in any case you need a Developer Account to sign an IPA to be able to install in iPhone, using any method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Attach the device
- XCode -> Window -> Devices
- Select the device
- Right click -> Show Provisioning Profiles
- Add your file, done.
- Under the Applications box, click +
- Select the .ipa file

Comment: "Show Provisioning Profiles" option not enabled in my xcode application.

Comment: Where can I get the provisioning profile? I got the .ipa via Expo (app made with React Native)

Comment: Awesome built in solution! :)

Answer (score 5):

Either Submit IPA for [TestFlight](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devdc42b26b8) on developer at ituneconnect  or Export your IPA with Development/Adhoc Profile (for registered Devices) and drag your ipa file at diawi or buildtry and generate a test link.

https://www.diawi.com/

there are more option try these also

1. https://www.installonair.com/
2. https://getappbox.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this by follow its instruction.. : https://www.diawi.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you jailbreak your phone, you can bypass the codesigning using AppSync.

You can't bypass codesigning unless you jailbreak.

Are these valid IPAs that have been signed by a dev account/apple?

Answer (score 0):

try this,you can install ipa by console https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller

Answer (score 0):

I try to face with these problems and I use : https://www.installonair.com . It's free and not have limit like diawi.

1. You need to add device UDID to apple developer account devices part.
2. Build your project and archieve it ad hoc with your certificate
3. Open that link and upload your ad hoc ipa file to website
4. Get qr code and link to download