# How to fix Xcode failing to install IPA on real IOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode

after I open devices view and drag and drop my IPA initially I see message "device is busy" and after some time see error "failed to install com.yourapp"

I looked into the `console` of the device and the error logs are https://pastebin.com/FG1qsXM8 (too long couldn't post here)

I am using xcode `Version 13.2.1 (13C100)`

and my iphone system is `15.1`

Final error looks like
[image]

Comment: There could be different reasons, but one the common issue is - 

`Device UUID is not added in Provisioning Profile for the bundleID`

Comment: @Abhishek that message is not present in my error logs. I posted the pastebin link with full error logs but cannot tell appart from them what is the reason

Answer (score 1):

- Copy youripa.ipa and change extension to zip.
- Open youripa.zip file.
- Go to Payload folder and Right click on Application.
- Show Package Contents.
- Check the `embedded.mobileprovision` file. (There are some
  information such as Team Id, Profile name, Provisioned devices etc.)

If it is **App Store Provision Profile**, you cannot install any device.

If it is **Development** or **Ad Hoc Provision Profile**, be sure your device is registered and included in that provision proile. You have to see your device UUID in the Provisioned devices list.

If it is Ad Hoc and your account is Enterprise (check the team name and id), you can do it. Probably you need to get profile from developer.apple.com or development team and [follow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42243360/3150441).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I did the steps and I see `ios Team Store Provisioning` so I don't see the ones you mentioned, neither "App Store" or "Development" or "Ad Hoc"

Comment: By the way, this is how I generate the IPA file `flutter build ios --release -t lib/main.dart` and after I run: `flutter build ipa`. The second command creates .xarchieve which I upload with xcode into appstore and also ipa as well. I am trying to run this ipa and test in my iphone before upload to appstore

Comment: PS: I see some hate on my question and -1 negative vote for some reason that is not clear to me. I think the question is clear enough and contains all the informations necessary including the error logs and versions

Comment: What other information does "ios Team Store Provisioning" have? You can see it by scrolling. Probably the type is App Store. So you cannot install it that way. Upload AppStore and use Testflight. Or create Ad Hoc profile, add your device. Open Xcode and change "ios Team Store Provisioning" to Ad Hoc profile. Then archive ipa again.
PS: -1 it's not me. :)

Comment: This is the information that I see https://ibb.co/vZP9gyw and https://ibb.co/F6n0Rq8